# How to make maven dependency local to project

Tags: java, maven

I have a **Project A** which needs project B as dependency.
Now my **Project B** has a dependency to a jar say **jarA** .
So I dont want Project A to have the jarA dependency.
Is there a way to do that

Comment: Option 1: exclude `jarA` where you declare the dependency on `ProjectB`.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what purpose `jarA` serves and why it should be a dependency of `projectB` but not `projectA`. Depending on the situation, there are different approaches. But I need to understand the background first.

Comment: HI @JFMeier Thanks for replying,
basically i have a spring boot app and a  util jar which is used by the spring boot app.
now i want to connect to database in my jar  so if i give spring data dependency it moves upto the spring boot app also and then my spring boot app also has access to db.
what i want is that only my util jar could connect to db and not the spring boot app.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an entry in the `<dependencyManagement>` of your spring boot app which sets the `<scope>` of your database dependency to `runtime`.

Then the spring boot app cannot use the database dependency in its code because it is only available at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

So don't import JarA in project A and import it in Project B directly.

Answer (score -1):

If your Project A has a direct dependency to Project B you keep that the way it is.

In Project B you set your dependency to jarA as

```
<dependency>
   <artifactId>jarA</artifactId>
   ...
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This limits the inheritance that the default scope `compile` would have.

If jarA is present in Project A, though its only defined in Project B you call it a transient dependency.